# Set Windows 10 default .pdf association for LoginVSI Users

Tags: windows-10, file-association, adobe-reader

I am attempting to change the default program for opening PDFs in a Horizon View pool to do some LoginVSI testing.

I am trying to change the default to Adobe Reader 11 that shipped with LoginVSI 4.1.4.2.

I have used DSIM to export an association list and set that through GPO to apply to the Horizon pool, but the changes are not reflected when my LoginVSI users sign in.

I changed my Master image to have Adobe set as the default (using an Admin account).

Every time I create a new pool and use my LoginVSI-generated users, the defaults are still set to Edge.

Any ideas on how to get this default changed, either through GPO or modifying the base image?

Comment: As a workaround you can set associations in HKCU\Software\Classes\.pdf instead of using the FileExts\UserChoice key. The latter is where your DISM XML applies the settings. HKCU\Software... is the per-user override area, that saves from all the trouble.

Comment: And I assume, you tried this exactly but didn't work? [Associate a file Type or protocol with a specific app using GPO](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/mrmlcgn/2013/02/26/windows-8-associate-a-file-type-or-protocol-with-a-specific-app-using-gpo-e-gdefault-mail-client-for-mailto-protocol/)

Comment: The second method works _after_ the initial login, but my use case is for non-persistent desktops.  This means that _every_ login is an initial login.  I haven't tried any registry attempts yet because until now I was able to use persistent desktops.  I will give it a shot and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by editing the .pdf entry in the OEMDefaultAssociations.xml file in system32

I took the xml entry I received as output from DISM after setting Adobe Reader as the default app and replaced the .pdf entry in OEMDefaultAssociations.xml with that line.

All in all, this is the only method I found to reliably prevent Edge from setting itself as the default PDF viewer on a profile create (users first login).

Answer (score -1):

Recently I found this article on www.loginvsi.com, it might be useful.

https://www.loginvsi.com/blog/518-fixing-default-file-type-associations-in-windows-10

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: LoginVSI was actually the application I was trying to use.  Their recommendations do not work for a nonpersistent use case.  On first login for a user, the GPO FTA is not applied.  It is only for subsequent logins that the FTA will work.

The recommendation for my answer below came from LoginVSI and they indicated they would update their blog post eventually.